# Merge rows that are mostly duplicate except for a column's binary value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am cleaning a database of movies. It was formed by merging 4 CSVs (4 streaming services' movies) into one. There are some movies that exist on two or more streaming services, like both Prime and Hulu.

I was able to merge the rest of the columns with:
`movies.groupby(compareColumns, group_keys=False)[allColumns].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())`

But now I'm left with rows that are practically identical except for their onPrime/onNetflix value (0=not available on service, 1=available on service).

For example, two rows I have are:

| name | onPrime | onHulu | otherColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Movie 1 | 1 | 0 | X |
| Movie 1 | 0 | 1 | X |

How do I systematically merge the two rows to have desired output below? (I have other columns that I don't want to be impacted)

Desired output:

| name | onPrime | onHulu | otherColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Movie 1 | 1 | 1 | X |

Not sure how I could do it through sum, bfill, ffill, or any built-in function.

I tried `filledgroups.fillna(value=0, axis=0, inplace=True, limit=1)`, where filledgroups is just a dataframe of two of the rows for trial, but it filled in 0s for other columns, whereas I only want to replace the 0s of onPrime/onHulu with 1s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping by **name** should do the trick..

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('name').max().reset_index()
```

With that approach, you group by name and aggregate using the max() function for all the columns.

If you wanted to apply differents aggregations to other columns you could use `agg()`:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('name').agg({'onPrime': 'max', 'onHulu': 'max', 'otherColumn': 'first'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: The first approach worked, thank you!